# Difference between cat file_name | sort, sort < file_name, sort file_name in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, stdin

Although they do give the same results, I wonder if there is some difference between them and which is the most appropriate way to sort something contained in a file.
Another thing which intrigues me is the use of delimiters, I noticed that the sort filter only works if you separate the strings with a new line, are there any ways to do this without having to write the new strings in a separate line

Comment: They are just multiple solutions to solve the same problem. Ways are endless, you can write sort program in C and sort using that. If you are writing it for a codebase, you would consider time and space complexity/portability/readability etc. If you are doing it for some general analysis, you would just care about how to achieve goal with less typing.

Comment: For example, like you asked for sorting a file delimited by something other than newline, you can achieve that by playing around with shell commands. Like for a comma delimited file, `tr ',' '\n' < file | sort`, first convert commas to newlines and then sort. Similarly this can be done with many other tools or builtin options.

Comment: The only difference I can think of is, that in `cat file | sort`, sort is unable to access file; thus it can't see the input's size, it can't mmap it (I don't really know if sort even does that), etc. and in others sort can directly access the file; I think any advantages/disadvantages would stem from this difference

Comment: @oguzismail, I am not sure but I guess `—mmap` arg separately needs to be given to mmap the file.

Answer (score 1):

The sort(1) command reads lines of text, analyzes and sorts them, and writes out the result. The command is intended to read *lines*, and lines in unix/linux are terminated by a *new line*.

The command takes its first non-option argument as the file to read; if there is no specification it reads *standard input*. So:

*sort file_name*

is a command line with such argument. The other two examples, "... | sort" and "sort < ..." do not specify the file to read directly to sort(1), but use its *standard input*. The effect, for what sort(1) is concerned, is the same.

> ways to do this without having to write the new strings in a separate line

Ultimately no. But if you want you can feed *sort* using another filter (a program), which reads the file non-linefeed-separated and creates lines to pass to sort. If such program exists and is named "myparse", you can do:

myparse non-linefeed-separated-file | sort

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `cat` involves creating a second process unnecessarily. This could be a performance issue if you perform many of such operation in a loop.

When doing input redirection to your file, the shell is setting up the association of file with std input. If the file would not exist, the shell complains about the file being missing.

When passing the file name as explicit argument, the `sort` process has to care about opening the file and to report an error if there is an accessability problem with it.